# Laravel remove column rollback

Tags: laravel

How to rollback if i remove specific column, for example

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::dropColumn('status');
}
public function down()
{
    // What goes here
}
```

I see there is no way to bring back the data so how to handle this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you are right once you've deleted a column, there is no way back to restore this column.

I would recommend to make [laravel backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup) before droping a column

```
php artisan backup:run --only-db
```

or in migration

```
public function up()
{
    Artisan::command('backup:run, ['--only-db' => true]);
    Schema::dropColumn('status');

}
```